# How to change stock status Instock permanently in magento2.3?

Tags: magento2.3, admin-panel, stock-status, cataloginventory

Please shown below image.

[image]

If quantity is 0 aur greater than 0 select Instock only. No need to select out of stock if quantity below 0.

Can i change this functionality through admin panel or need to do some code.

**How to do that ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "**Manage Stock**" as "**No**" in **Advanced inventory** section, under the "**Quantity**" field on the product. This will always show the product as **In Stock** on the frontend.

Check this screenshot:

[image]

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks..its work for me.